# Reuse a button in WFP application

Tags: wpf, windows-8

I'm developing my first win8 application. And I need to create a log off button on several pages.
In general this is a button with some text and image inside.

What approach should I choose: crate a template, a resource or style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `style` to reuse a button. The style should define its `template` and a `resource` is just available based on where it is defined.

Sample of a style targeting the button that you defined with `x:Key` to be reused everywhere else. If you did not specify `x:Key` and the `style` is defined in the `Application Resources` then it will apply the style to all of your buttons.

```
<Style x:Key="CustomStyleButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#373737" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
<Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />

<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border CornerRadius="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Grid>
                    <Path x:Name="PathIcon" Width="15" Height="25" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#4C87B3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,0,0,0" Data="F1 M 30.0833,22.1667L 50.6665,37.6043L 50.6665,38.7918L 30.0833,53.8333L 30.0833,22.1667 Z "/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />                                
                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E59400" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    <Setter TargetName="PathIcon" Property="Fill" Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="OrangeRed" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Sample usage

```
<Button Width="200" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource CustomStyleButton}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
<Button.Content>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Watch Now" FontSize="20" />
        <TextBlock Text="Duration: 50m" FontSize="12" Foreground="Gainsboro" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button.Content>
```

Comment: Can I add an image inside the button? Or put another control?

Comment: There are a plethora of things you can do to style the button exactly as you want. Do some searching to learn more. Here's one resource that can help you with styling: http://wpftutorial.net/Styles.html

Comment: @Ask You can if you restyle the template property of the button. You don't need to use the `control` to hack around it. Think of the style as your only `fashion designer` that takes care of the `style` of your button

Comment: @lll thx for your answer - the above works if you want a button which looks the same and has the same triggers etc. - but i have many buttons which remove selected items from various listboxes - i do not want to have to create a separate handler for each button which does basically the same thing - (removes selected items from a listbox) do you have any advice on how to make it more DRY?